# Submit form with no action atribute pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

```
<form action="" name="searchForm" id="searchForm" method="post">
```

How can I make it submit using Javascript when user press enter?

edit: assuming I can't edit the `<html>`, only using JS (jQuery if really needed)

edit2: it will also be great if `myFormProcessFunction()` was loaded

accept

Just capture the submit function as if the form had been submitted via the enter button normally.

```
document.searchForm.submit = function()
{
    myFormProcessFunction()

    return false; // prevents default action
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture the `submit` function as if the form had been submitted via the enter button normally.

```
document.searchForm.submit = function()
{
    //do something

    return false; // prevents default action
}
```

Comment: I edited the question, so do you think that with that code; when user hits ENTER; the js function will be load it? (that function retrieves all the input values and sends the $.ajax via post

Comment: @Toni Typically when any element of a form is currently focussed and a user hits Enter, the form is submitted.  Whatever way the form is submitted, this code will capture that event, allow you to do something like your ajax call, and prevent the default action which should be to submit the form to the URL contained in the `action` attribute (which defaults to the current page if empty or not there).

Comment: @Toni note the solution from Grigor is equally valid, it is just a jQuery version as opposed to a pure js version.  There are many cases where the jQuery version provides more robustness but as far as I know, the submit event is universal across browsers so my version is mildly lighter weight.

Comment: Thanks! the problem is that in the form there is not submit input (its not my code :()

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function(e) {     
   e.preventDefault();
   return false; 
})
```

try that, I am sure it'll work. It uses jQuery plulgin, so make sure you have it included.

Comment: but isn't that the oposite i need? i need to send the form via post, thanks!

Comment: edited the question, what if instead of your e.preventDefault() i write myFormProcessFunction()???